# Add packages only to test projects in a folder using Directory.Build.props

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild

I am already using `Directory.Build.props` to add certain packages to all the C# projects like this:

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference 
      Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" 
      Version="1.2.0-beta.435"
      PrivateAssets="all" 
      Condition="$(MSBuildProjectExtension) == '.csproj'" 
    />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Now I added a `Test` folder to the solution where I want to store all the tests, the folder tree look like this:

[image]

The folder it's a solution folder and appears in the `sln` file.

How can I create a condition to add `xunit` and `Moq` to only the `csproj` inside that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following approach only works if `Test` is a folder on the file system instead of a solution folder:

You can add another `Directory.Build.Props` into the `Test` folder and include the parent folder's `Directory.Build.Props` like this:

```xml
<Project>
  <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('Directory.Build.props', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" />
 <!-- Your content -->
</Project>
```

Since your question is about packages you could also consider [Central Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/Central-Package-Management) as an alternative.

Comment: The solution folder is actually also a file system folder, so it worked like a charm! Thank you! So with CPM I have a centralized way to control the version of the other packages (that aren't installed for all projects)?

Comment: Yes, i think so. But to be honest I have not worked with CPM, yet.

Comment: I tried it and it seems working great. I just have to remember to add manually the packages in the `csproj` file because I am using vscode + vscode-solution-explorer to install packages and it doesn't have the option to not specify the version (managed by CPM).